# Shear connections

Tags: structures

Question: which of the three shear connections (beam/column) below will require diagonal bracing?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Usually, there is no need for diagonal bracing. The details A and B are not suited for diagonal bracing.

Detail C for large span beams under heavy loads can have triangular stiffeners welded on the bottom between the two sides, but that kind of connection is not encouraged. If the girder or heavy beam connects to support or column, custom-designed connections are employed because of limitations on the detail C type configuration.

For A and B if the loads warrant they add horizontal web stiffeners as per this.[image: horizontal stiffener plates]

Comment: The shear plates/tabs in the image you showed above could potentially be braced with addition of the gusset. But which other type of connections are suitable for bracing?

Comment: There are huge amount of literature and research on steel connections. Shear, moment, ductile,  super plastic limit and beyond. Many steel frame buildings are designed for push over plastic joints, highly complex behavior design to withstand very large earthquakes at the expense of energy absorbing joints deforming into prescribed wrinkles.